# Feedback Request - Restarting Docker container on file change

Tags: docker, docker-compose, suricata

I have this working but was wondering if there is any potential side effects or even a better way to do this.  The example below is generic.

I have a docker-compose file with two containers (`container_1` and `container_2`).

`container_1` exposes a volume that contains various config files that it uses to run the installed service.

`container_2` mounts the volume from `container_1` and periodically runs a script that pulls files and updates the config of the service running in `container_1`.

Every time the configs are updated I want to restart the service in `container_1` without having to use `cron` or some of the other methods I have seen discussed.

**My solution:**

I put a script on `container_1` that checks if the config file has been updated (the file is initially empty and that md5sum is stored in a separate file) and if the file has changed based on md5sum it updates the current hash and kills the process.

In the compose file I have a `healthcheck` that runs the script periodically and `restart` is set to `always`.  When the script in `container_2` runs and updates the config files in `container_1` the `monitor_configs.sh` the script on `container_1` will kill the process of the service and the container will be restarted and reload the configs.

**monitor_config.sh**

```
# current_hash contains md5sum of empty file initially
#!/bin/sh

echo "Checking if config has updated"
config_hash=$(md5sum /path/to/config_file)
current_hash=$(cat /path/to/current_file_hash)

if [ "$rules_hash" != "$current_hash" ] 
then
    echo "config has been updated, restarting service"
    md5sum /path/to/config_file > /path/to/current_file_hash
    kill $(pgrep service)
else
    echo "config unchanged"
fi
```

**docker-compose.yml**

```
version: '3.2'
services:
  service_1:
    build:
      context: /path/to/Dockerfile1
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD-SHELL", "/usr/bin/monitor_config.sh"]
      interval: 1m30s
      timeout: 10s
      retries: 1
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - type: volume
        source: conf_volume
        target: /etc/dir_from_1

  service_2:
    build:
      context: /path/to/Dockerfile2
    depends_on:
      - service_1
    volumes:
      - type: volume
        source: conf_volume
        target: /etc/dir_from_1

volumes:
  conf_volume:
```

I know this is not the intended use of `healthcheck` but it seemed like the cleanest way to get the desired effect while still maintaining only one running process in each container.

I have tried with and without `tini` in `container_1` and it seems to work as expected in both cases.

I plan on extending the `interval` of the `healthcheck` to 24 hours as the script in `container_2` only runs once a day.

**Use case**

I'm running Suricata in `container_1` and pulledpork in `container_2` to update the rules for Suricata.  I want to run pulledpork once a day and if the rules have been update, restart Suricata to load the new rules.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may want to look at how tools like [confd](https://github.com/kelseyhightower/confd) work, which would run as your container_1 entrypoint. It runs in the foreground, polls an external configuration source, and upon a change it rewrites the config files inside the container and restarts the spawned application.

To make your own tool like confd you'd need to include your restart trigger, maybe your health monitoring script, and then make the stdin/stdout/stderr pass through along with any signals so that your restart tool becomes transparent inside the container.

Comment: Thank you...I will definitely have to take a look at confd, it looks like it could help out in a few other things I'm working on as well.